# What is the point of a 10GBPS internet connection?

Tags: 10gbethernet

At a few dedicated server companies, they offer 10GBPS internet connections to replace the normal connection that you get if you order a server from them.

I can see some applications of a 10GBPS network connection (for example, the mainframe of an enterprise company), but even this sort of application would require more than one physical server, and these companies only offer this 10GBPS link for one server (if you have more than a single server, you have to purchase more 10GBPS internet connections).

Since it is not physically possible (at the moment) to carry data across the internet at 10GBPS, what sort of application which would use only a single dedicated server and use most of the 10GBPS internet connection?

Here's some of what I have come up with:

- Enterprise email
- Very busy website (100's connections per second)
- Game server (one of those big ones like in World of Warcraft where you can have 10,000+ users on at the same time)

Comment: You're stuck thinking it would be 1 connection at 10Gbps, where it's more likely 10,000 at around 1Mbps.. which a heavily trafficed website streaming video could easily do.

Comment: Also, I've seen them offer 64GB of memory, while 640kB should be more than enough for anyone :)

Comment: pr0n, pr0n and more streaming pr0n videos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 10Gbps connection may be very useful to externalize backup out of your server but still within the datacenters.

There are many datacenters where multiple providers are interconnected with 10Ggbps or even 40Gbps and therefore your 10Gbps can be very handy when transferring multiple Terabytes of data. With a 1 or 2 Gbps it wouldn't be possible within 24h.